# passing selected text as a parameter in slickC

Tags: slickedit

I am trying to get text in a selection to be passed to the function 
find_max_eq_filter originally.  The function I am trying to modify had an 
"s" parameter which I assume is the selection text.  I want to change the 
function to allow a parameter that is passed by the user. Could someone
clue me in how to do this?

```
    _command void align_equals() name_info(','VSARG2_MARK|VSARG2_REQUIRES_EDITORCTL)
    {

       if ( _select_type() != "LINE" && _select_type() != "BLOCK" ) {
          message("A LINE or BLOCK selection is required for this function");
          return;
       }

       gMaxEqCol = 0;

       _str character = prompt(prmt1, 'What do you wish to align?'); /* I want to ask the user for an input string */
       filter_selection(find_max_eq_filter(s, character));  /* Here I want to pass the selection with the string taken from the user. */

       if (gMaxEqCol == 0) {
          // no equal signs
          return;
       }

       filter_selection(align_eq_filter);
       _free_selection("");
    }


    static _str find_max_eq_filter(s, _str toalign)
    {
       _str inputStr = expand_tabs(s)
       int equalsPos = pos(toalign, inputStr, 1, "");
       if ( equalsPos > gMaxEqCol  ) {
          gMaxEqCol = equalsPos;
       }

       return s;
    }
```

filter_selection(find_max_eq_filter);

Any help appreciated,

Ted

PS. you want to reproduce what I am doing so I'll have to paste the whole thing:

```
     #include "slick.sh"

     static int gMaxEqCol;
     static _str gUsrStr;

     static _str find_max_char_filter(s)
     {
        _str inputStr = expand_tabs(s);
        int equalsPos = pos(gUsrStr, inputStr, 1, "");
        if ( equalsPos > gMaxEqCol  ) {
           gMaxEqCol = equalsPos;
        }

        return s;
     }

     static _str align_char_filter(s)
     {
        if (gMaxEqCol <= 0 || length(s) == 0) {
           return s;
        }

        _str expandedStr = expand_tabs(s);

        int equalsPos  = pos(gUsrStr, expandedStr, 1, "");
        if (equalsPos == 0) {
           return s;
        }

        _str prefix    = substr(expandedStr, 1, equalsPos - 1);
        _str postfix   = substr(expandedStr,equalsPos);

        while (equalsPos < gMaxEqCol ) {
           prefix = prefix :+ ' ';
           ++equalsPos;
        }

        return prefix :+ postfix;
     }

     _command void align_chars() name_info(','VSARG2_MARK|VSARG2_REQUIRES_EDITORCTL)
     {

        if ( _select_type() != "LINE" && _select_type() != "BLOCK" ) {
           message("A LINE or BLOCK selection is required for this function");
           return;
        }

        gMaxEqCol = 0;
        _str prmpt1 = "";
        gUsrStr   = prompt(prmpt1, "Please enter a string: ");
        filter_selection(find_max_char_filter);

        if (gMaxEqCol == 0) {
           // no equal signs
           return;
        }
        filter_selection(align_char_filter);
        _free_selection("");
     }
```

So this is my problem, I want to change gUsrStr to be a parameter of the helper functions instead of having a global variable for it. However, when I try to do that it breaks. Also, I do not quite understand the first argument of the prompt function. What is it suppposed to be? Is it a default value in case the user does not enter anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not posting the relevant part,
I think you should post the header of the calling function ...

But I'll try my hand at a partial answer, then update if you update the question ...

Does it have any of these tags?
`VSARG2_REQUIRES_AB_SELECTION`, or `VSARG2_REQUIRES_SELECTION`  (or really anything with `REQUIRE` and `SELECTION` - if so try to remove them

Are there any `select_active()` checks?  follow those or disable them

Also are you trying to invoke it interactively or just from another slick-c code?

Many years ago I figured some of this out when I wrote `narrow.e`, allowing me to emulate emacs' `narrow-to-region`.  I used it to base my answer (`narrow.e` [is posted here](http://community.slickedit.com/index.php?topic=6779.0) for the full example).

Comment: Well I am actually trying to modify an example from valen to allow me to specify what character I want to align, instead of it always being an equal sign. http://community.slickedit.com/index.php?topic=5899.0

Comment: Thanks for the edit ... but as I don't exactly know (or care to know) the purpose of the whole script - can we reduce it to just what you are trying to do with the selection?   (1) What will the user highlight before invoking your function?  A character, a word? complete lines?  (2) what does _select_typ() return for you?   (3) if you do reduce the function, can you skip the prompt?   I want to reproduce your selection issue without debugging your whole script, thanks :)

Comment: I have updated the question with the code I am trying to change. I got it to work with a global variable. I also don't understand what the first argument of them prompt function does.

Comment: I really meant for you to include a SMALLER example, one that just focuses on your issues with selection.   I still need answers on the other questions in my comment

Comment: Oh well, I'll have to do that later. I have pretty much gotten it to work now but I really hate the hack I am doing with the prompt function of just simply declaring an empty variable called prmpt="" and passing it as the first argument. What is this first argument anyway. I don't what the first argument for the function prompt is for.